# images on Heroku Deploy not showing up

Tags: html, css, image, heroku

I'm having an issue where only 1 of my images shows up when deploying to Heroku whereas all show up on localhost. The one that shows up is

```
<div class="hero-wrap ftco-degree-bg" style="background-image: url('images/bg_1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
```

Where I'm pulling the image with url(), but every other instance where I try to do this in the code (three different attempts):

```
<a class="img" id="albumPhoto1" style="background-image: url('../images/greenPurplegrad.jpg');"></a>
<a class="img" id="albumPhoto2" style="background-image: url('./images/yellowPinkgrad.jpg');"></a>
<a class="img" id="albumPhoto3" style="background-image: url('images/pinkBluegrad.jpg');"></a>
```

But if I set the url as

```
style="background-image: url('images/bg_1.jpg");"
```

(the same as the first image that shows up) the image will show. Obviously I don't want all the same image, so I'd like some help in seeing where I went wrong.

Here's an image of the images folder to show I have all these images in the correct location:
[Images Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa05j.png)

Yes, all of them are .jpg

The web app can be found here: [My Web App on Heroku](https://spotlightspotify.herokuapp.com)
If you just press the search-icon, right below it some images (as seen above) should pop up, but they don't

EDIT:
Added image of file structure:
[Public folder with HTML and images folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfW6g.png)

EDIT 2:
Something weird to note is that if I change any image to the bg_1.jpg, it will show up, but if I change the section with bg_1.jpg to any other image, it won't show up on the background. So I believe my images may be corrupted somehow even though I can see them in the folder.

Comment: can you post your file structure? at least the part concern to your images.
also, did you try: try to enter the images URL without the two dots in the beginning.
eg: **`url('/images/pinkBluegrad.jpg');`** instead of `url('../images/pinkBluegrad.jpg');`

Comment: Yes, and I will be testing as well. Is there any reason why the first image, bg_1.jpg is able to be seen with only url('images/bg_1.jpg') but none of the other ones are?

Comment: Based on your file structure, I think that changing the URL path to **`url('/images/pinkBluegrad.jpg');`** should work.
for your other question - **I** personally **didn't saw any image** after pressing the search bar in your web app.

Comment: I meant the image that is with the search bar, that blue and orange gradient is bg_1.jpg, but yes, thank you for looking at the web app itself.

Comment: the image with the search bar is not an image, it is a linear-gradient for a background. If you'll add **`background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 3%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 54%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);`** to a div, it will give you the same result. in case you are going to change that, use the prefixes for other browsers (mozilla -moz-, safari -webkit-, microsoft -ms-, opera -o-). e.g: `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 3%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 54%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);`

Comment: The image is an image, and the gradient is a white to gray gradient if the image doesn't pop up, I did see where you got that from in the CSS though. You can see bg_1.jpg in the images folder I already had in my post. Which is called on in the first code section of the post as well. This image is called on successfully while the rest are not. Tried changing the url path to only url('/images/pinkBluegrad.jpg'); to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because of a dynamic address, when you type `"../image.jpg"` or `"image.jpg"`, you are defining a static address, this is practical for local application, but not for PHP .. .

I don't know exactly if this is the center of the problem, but try this: `background: url ("/path/to/file/image.jpg")`

when you type the first "/" you are taking the current file and having it search from this file.

[image]

Comment: I have the images folder in the same folder as the HTML that's running on the web app, which is why I refer to ../images/image.jpg. I'm happy to try it when I get home though, thank you.

Comment: When you have images in the same directory you can use `"/image.jpg"`, a little tip, create a separate folder for the images for "good practices", because it can get disorganized and you have to warm your head up little thing.

Comment: Emphasis on the folder, I already had it in a separate folder, refer to the edited image on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Still unsure of what caused the inability to load every image but bg_1.jpg, but since Heroku has its ephemeral filesystem, I'm led to believe that the images are being deleted from the system since I cannot call on these images whereas bg_1.jpg is directly implemented in the program.

As such, I found an [Online image holder + HTML](https://ibb.co/) to store the images for me and I directly and freshly call these images any time I need them with the url() css. This eliminates the need to have the images folder at all since they are now all online. If this is inconvenient, Heroku sponsors Amazon S3 to hold files as well (I think that's how it works?).

I hope this helps someone, but I don't believe anyone else has been having these types of issues with Heroku in a few years.